# Ubuntu 22.04 switching between amd gpu's

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, radeon

I have a laptop with A10-9600P processor and Radeon R7 M440 gpu, I want to be able to switch to integrated gpu sometimes. I've tried to update the drivers from the amd website by downloading `amdgpu-install.deb` file, installing it with `sudo apt-get install ./amdgpu-install-VERSION.deb` and then running `amdgpu-install` as it says in the instruction. The install seemed to be completed since there were no errors, but there weren't any new apps or something like that, so I still can't switch between gpu's. `dpkg -l amdgpu-pro` didn't find anything and `sudo lshw -c video` says i'm using just `amdgpu`. Did I do something wrong? And how do I do it correctly then?